# SQL Query Conversation issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

```
SELECT"
  dateadd(s,convert(bigint, mcdt.FROMDATE) / 1000,convert(datetime, '1-2-1970 00:00:00')
  ) AS "From Date",FROM "MaintenanceContract" "mcdt"
`end`
`your text`
```

Getting the below error as

> "Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
> converting expression to data type varchar."

please advise

Comment: Make sure the data type of the FROMDATE column can be safely converted to a bigint.

Comment: There are so many quoting errors there. What does the real code look like? What's the data type of the `FROMDATE` column in the underlying table?

Comment: The problem could be your ambiguous date; why not use an unambiguous format? Do you still get an error?

Comment: Also, what does the Query Store have to do with the matter? Are you questioning the query plan? What does the plan have to do with the error you provide?

Comment: SELECT
  "mcdt"."CONTRACTNAME" AS "Contract Name",
  dateadd(
    s,
    convert(bigint, mcdt.FROMDATE) / 1000,
    convert(datetime, '1-2-1970 00:00:00')
  ) AS "From Date",
  dateadd(
    s,
    convert(bigint, mcdt.TODATE) / 1000,
    convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00')
  ) AS "To Date",
  "mcdt"."TOTALPRICE" AS "Total Price"
FROM
  "MaintenanceContract" "mcdt"
  order by [From Date] desc